# how to force us the php 8.1 installed using home brew?

Tags: php, macos, version, mamp

I Have installed MAMP in my mac, Using the php version of 7.4.

```
command which php
```

returns - /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.21/bin/php

I have installed php 8.1 using brew.
I comment the ~/.bash_profile

```
# export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.21/bin:$PATH
# alias mysql=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql
# export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@13/bin:$PATH"
```

but still its show the same php path . How to shift to newly installed php version?

Answer (score 7):

You have to link which version of PHP you want to use.

`brew unlink php` will unlink the current version of PHP.
`brew link php@8.1` will link with PHP 8.1 (you need to install it before)